# How to tell if a string could have been generated by formatting another string?

Tags: python, string-formatting

Say we have:

```py
f = "The object named '{}' is corrupted."
s = "The object named 'my_object' is corrupted."
```

`s` is equal to `f.format("my_object")`. If we didn't know that, how could we check if `s` can be generated by formatting `f`? Is there a function to do that in the standard library?

This can be done using regex but we'd have to reimplement the logic of how `format` works (e.g., curly braces are replaced with any string, etc). This is why I'd like to know if there's a way to use the same logic that `str.format` uses.

Comment: You can convert your formatting string into a regex automatically though, and then check if a particular string matches this template. Just replace `{}` with `.*` in the formatting string. It will be hard to support just ANY formatting syntax though

Comment: I think this package, [`parse`](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse), answers my question. It's presented as "the opposite of format()". Also the fact that it exists points toward a gap in the std lib for that.

Comment: Or not, as the same argument could be made for *any* third party package. (OT)